# Why isn't my GUI working, do I need a visible code?

Tags: java

I have a homework problem where I am trying to set up a GUI and do the following:

```
  Step 1. Create a random list of 52 elements holding 52 numbers 
           corresponding to 52 cards in the cards folder

   Step 2. Create a JFrame
        2a. set title of your frame
        2b. set layout of your frame to have a GridLayout

   Step 3. Create 3 cards
        3a. create 3 objects of ImageIcon whose image's location is 
            pointing to the image in the cards folder
        3b. create 3 JLabel object, each one hold an ImageIcon object 
            created above

   Step 4. Add three JLabel into your JFrame

   Step 5. Pack and display your frame
```

I am having trouble trying to make my GUI visible and I am also having problems understanding how to implement the ImageIcon. I need to do a Grid Layout, but none of it is showing up.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Question_2 {

   static String location = "cards/";

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      String[] cards;
      cards = new String[ 52 ];

      JFrame frmMyWindow = new JFrame( "Random Cards" );
      frmMyWindow.setSize( 300, 200 );
      frmMyWindow.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
      frmMyWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

      frmMyWindow.setVisible( true );
   }

}

class frmMyWindow extends JFrame {

   JLabel lblName;
   JPanel panelMain, panelLeft, panelCenter, panelRight;
   private int realityState;
   private int commState;

   public frmMyWindow( String Cards ) {
      super( "Cards" );
      realityState = commState = 0;

      lblName = new JLabel( "Cards" );
      panelMain = new JPanel( new GridLayout( 1, 3, 10, 10 ) );
      setLayout( new BorderLayout( 20, 10 ) );

      add( lblName, BorderLayout.NORTH );

      add( panelMain, BorderLayout.CENTER );

      panelLeft = new JPanel( new FlowLayout( FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 10 ) );
      panelCenter = new JPanel( new FlowLayout( FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5 ) );
      panelRight = new JPanel( new FlowLayout( FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 10 ) );

      panelMain.add( panelLeft );
      panelMain.add( panelCenter );
      panelMain.add( panelRight );

   }

}
```

I wanted the code to show up where there is a title that has the word Cards and then the grid layout with the 3 randomly chosen cards from the card file.

Comment: So an immediate problem I see is that you do not set the Jframe to Gridlayout.  You set the JPanel, but not the JFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine except you are creating `JFrame` instance instead of your custom class.

The following line

```
JFrame frmMyWindow = new JFrame( "Random Cards" );
```

Should be

```
JFrame frmMyWindow = new frmMyWindow( "Random Cards" );
```

Comment: Thank you!! Do you know how to input the card pictures into the program so it will show up in the GUI?